# PgAdmin 4 - how to see output message of every query

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have 100 update queries, I run all in one go just pressing F5 on PGadmin query editor. But I only see "updated count" for the last query. How can I see the result message of all 100 update queries.
If I see the message in Query History tab, it also shows only last message.

Although this is a very basic requirement to validate my data correction queries output before running on production. But I dont see any kind of help on google.

Please help, if there would be any other solution.

Comment: Sorry I think you are out of luck. Showing the results of queries is the responsibility of the client. In this pgAdmin. When a series of queries showing the last one appears to be just how pgAdmin works. If you can give DBeaver a try, when multiple queries independent it will normally give a result tab for each;

Comment: @Belayer-  But you made my luck :) . DBeaver is perfect for my need, It's "Execute Sql Script"  feature shows the result of every query. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PGAdmin doesn't have such feature, I have tried a lot. But @Belayer comment helped me with alternate solution.

So we can achieve this by using `DBeaver universal database tool`. Steps:

1. download and install free **`"DBeaver"`** tool.
2. create connection with your database.
3. paste your all the queries in query script editor, and use `"Execute SQL Script (Alt+X)" option` to run them all together. DBeaver will execute query one after another till end and will keep displaying the result parallel in different window called `"Execution Log".` We can see here number of row updated, Duration, Success or Fail status etc.
4. DBeaver has one another window called `"Statistic"` that shows summary of the result of all the queries like number of total rows updated, Execution time etc.